# Unzip and rename files with a batch (Windows)

Tags: batch-file, archive

I'm very new at batch files and have some troubles with my code.  I had investigated in other questions of this page but can't still do my task. I have multiples zipped folders in the same directory with an .html file inside each one. I need to unzip the folders and rename the .html with the name of the folder.

Example:

```
FolderA.zip with file xyz.html
FolderB.zip with file abc.html
```

Result:

```
file FolderA.html
file FolderB.html
```

This is my code:

```
cd C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') DO (
set nombre2=%%~naI
"C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa
for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b *.html') do (
ren %%I %nombre2%.html
 ) 
)
DEL *.zip
```

Comment: I can**not** understand how the `ren` command can give `FolderA.zip with file xyz.html` result? Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

- The for loop variable iterating the html files is `%%f` not `%%I`.
- You would also need [delayed
  expansion](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) setting and using a
  variable in a (code block).
- The modfiers `~na` will return name and attributes?

---

```
@Echo off
cd C:\Users\MyUser\Desktop
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') DO (
     "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa
    for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b *.html') do (
        ren ""%%f" "%%~nI.html"
    ) 
)
DEL *.zip
```

Answer (score 1):

I have come after many years to this post and helped me a lot.
I needed to correct minor thing in user6811411's solution to make it works fine. I will put it here, might help someone else.

Run it from .bat file:

```
@Echo off
cd C:\Users\3566597\Desktop\npritingog
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') DO (
     "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa
    for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b *.html') do (
        ren "%%f" "%%~nI.html"
    ) 
)
```

If you want to run it from the command line then you need to replace each `%%` with `%`