# batch zip extract and rename with zip file name

Tags: batch-file, archive

Looking for unzip files using 7zip and rename the unzipped files and add Zip file name to sub files.
upto this code batch extracted but not working for rename Resource from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45624431/unzip-and-rename-files-with-a-batch-windows)

```
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') DO (
 "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa

 for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /a-d /b *.html') do (
        ren ""%%f" "%%~nI.html"
    ) 
)
```

how to achieve this help us

Answer (score 0):

```
for /F %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar') DO (
 "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -o"%%~dpI" "%%I" -aoa

 for %%f in (*.jpg) do (
    ren "%%f" "%%~nI.jpg"
)

 for %%f in (*.eps) do (
   ren "%%f" "%%~nI.eps"
)

for %%f in (*.ai) do (
   ren "%%f" "%%~nI.ai"
)

for %%f in (*.png) do (
   ren "%%f" "%%~nI.png"
)

)
```